# Markers on map leaflet for shiny

Tags: r, geolocation, shiny, leaflet

Is there a way to set visible markers (plural) on a leaflet map, when a user clicks on this map in a shiny application? Furthermore, is it possible to retrieve the coordinates of this marker?

If not in shiny, can you do that in leaflet JS?

Comment: Do you have any live examples with leaflet or any other mapping libraries in or out of R demonstrating the interactivity you would like to achieve?

Comment: @timelyportfolio I want a marker to pop up when I click on the map with my mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to be specific without any code, but here are the basics.

1) Shiny/Leaflet lets you subscribe to events such as mouse click. If your map is called `MyMap` you would use the code:

```
ClickVar<-input$MyMap_click
```

then `ClickVar` is a reactive variable - a list, that includes the lat, long and the `layerId`.

Now that you have the lat and long you can use that to add your popup. Do all of this in an `observerEvent` like so:

```
observeEvent( input$MyMap_click, {
    ClickVar<-input$MyMap_click
    addPopups(MyMap, lng=ClickVar$lng, lat=ClickVar$lat, popup="Here I am")
})
```

Note - I have not tested this so you may need to alter it slightly. You may also want to think about removing one popup when another is clicked, assigning them a `layerID` or `group` etc.

Comment: is there a way to store the MAPID_map_click?  I would like to use those clicks to update my `updateSelectInput`